# Initialize variables in the Component Pascal by default

Tags: integer, component-pascal

Integer type variables are initialized by default in a strange way.
Look at this code:

```
MODULE MyTest;
    IMPORT Log;
    PROCEDURE Start*;
    VAR a, b, c, d: INTEGER; (* This variables *) 
    BEGIN
        Log.Int(a);
        Log.Ln;
        Log.Int(b);
        Log.Ln;
        Log.Int(c);
        Log.Ln;
        Log.Int(d);
        Log.Ln;
    END Start;
END MyTest
```

Here is the result:

4233640
2287340
2287344
576

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this? It's not standard Pascal, Delphi, or FreePascal. You've also not asked a question.

Comment: He says Component Pascal, which is afaik closer to Oberon2 than to Pascal. It was rebranded for marketing reasons. The .NET version is one of the original 5-6 .NET languages afaik.  the pedigree is Pascal ->m2->m3->Oberon->Oberon2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most Wirthian languages, probably variables(and specially local ones) are probably uninitialized. They *may* be initialized by chance, but usually there is no guarantee.